# Passing another instance of the same class and comparing it's stored values to current stored values

Tags: java

Last objective of my assignment asks to create a method `matches()`. It receives another `GenericMemoryCell` as a parameter, and returns true if both of its stored values can be found in the stored values of the current `GenericMemoryCell`. Order of stored values is not important.

Creating the method was not difficult, but I am lost on how to call it from `main()` because I cannot wrap my head around the concept of passing another instance of `GenericMemoryCell`. Where am I getting another pair of `storedValueA` and `storedValueB` in the first place? Is `matches()` "running" a virtual instance of the entire program within itself?

```
import java.util.*;

public class GenericMemoryCell<T>{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter valueA: ");
        String readerA = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter valueB: ");
        String readerB = input.next();

        GenericMemoryCell<String> values = new GenericMemoryCell<>(readerA, readerB);
        System.out.println("storedValueA: " + values.readA());
        System.out.println("storedValueB: " + values.readB());

        values.writeA(readerA);
        values.writeB(readerB);
    }

    public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueA, T storedValueB)
    { this.storedValueA = storedValueA; this.storedValueB = storedValueB; writeA(storedValueA); writeB(storedValueB); }

    public T readA()
    { return storedValueA; }

    public T readB()
    { return storedValueB; }

    public void writeA(T x)
    { storedValueA = x; }

    public void writeB(T y)
    { storedValueB = y; }

    public boolean matches(GenericMemoryCell<T> that){
        return (this.storedValueA.equals(that.storedValueA) && this.storedValueB.equals(that.storedValueB)); }

    private T storedValueA, storedValueB;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to understand the difference between static and non static methods...

Comment: @Leo, the methods must all operate on the object making the call (none are static).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```
public class GenericMemoryCell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMemoryCell g1 = new GenericMemoryCell();
        //set g1 values here

        GenericMemoryCell g2 = new GenericMemoryCell();
        //set g2 values here

        System.out.println(g1.matches(g2));

    }

    public boolean matches(GenericMemoryCell g) {
        //implement the logic here
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, it might work for you. However, if you want system to ask for inputs repeatedly, you need to some kind of `loop`.

```
public class GenericMemoryCell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter first input: ");
        int firstInput = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter second input");
        int secondInput = scanner.nextInt();
        list.add(firstInput);
        list.add(secondInput);

        Scanner scannerObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter first input: ");
        int firstArg = scannerObj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter second input: ");
        int secondArg = scannerObj.nextInt();
        boolean isMatches = isInputMatches(firstArg, secondArg, list);
        if (isMatches) {
            System.out.println("These inputs were already stored before. Please try again with different inputs");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The inputs are successfully stored. Thank you.");
        }
        scanner.close();
        scannerObj.close();

    }

    private static boolean isInputMatches(int firstArg, int secondArg, List<Integer> list) {
        return list.contains(firstArg) && list.contains(secondArg);
    }
}
```